# Pandas: Comma Separated Excel Cells not Converting to List

Tags: python, pandas

I've joined 3 Excel tab data sets to give me my base dataframe, and then for each line I want to count the int values in the comma separated values in DUAlloc and divide Amount by the DUAlloc Count then loop through the DuAlloc list and assign individual lines e.g.

Base Data:

| Description | DuAlloc | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Blah | 1,2,3,4,5 | 1000 |
| Yada | 30,15,3,4,5 | 200 |

Processed Data:

| Description | DuAlloc | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Blah | 1 | 200 |
| Blah | 2 | 200 |
| Blah | 3 | 200 |
| Yada | 3 | 40 |
| Blah | 4 | 200 |
| Yada | 4 | 40 |
| Blah | 5 | 200 |
| Yada | 5 | 40 |
| Yada | 15 | 40 |
| Yada | 30 | 40 |

I've tried numerous ways to convert to a list: list(), tolist(), but either get the same number for all the counts, or the nearest I've come is `[len(str(c)) for c in df3['DUAlloc']]` which counts all the characters which I don't want.

How would I go about achieving this, and is Pandas the best route to take?

Comment: Were  you storing lists of numbers within cells in your excel spreadsheets? How did you get to that point? Excel and pandas both operate much better with individual values in the cells

Comment: Its a POC, we'll be using lists in CosmoDb once up and running. Just learning Python and the best ways to do things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), [`df.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), [`Groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and [`df.div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html):

```
In [501]: out = df.assign(DuAlloc=df['DuAlloc'].str.split(',')).explode('DuAlloc')

In [506]: out['Amount'] = out['Amount'].div(out.groupby('Description')['Amount'].transform('size'))

In [507]: out
Out[507]: 
  Description DuAlloc  Amount
0        Blah       1   200.0
0        Blah       2   200.0
0        Blah       3   200.0
0        Blah       4   200.0
0        Blah       5   200.0
1        Yada      30    40.0
1        Yada      15    40.0
1        Yada       3    40.0
1        Yada       4    40.0
1        Yada       5    40.0
```

Comment: Thank you! An elegant solution to my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.str.count` to count the number of `,` in columns.

```py
out = (df.assign(Amount=df['Amount'].div(df['DuAlloc'].str.count(',').add(1)),
                 DuAlloc=df['DuAlloc'].str.split(','))
       .explode('DuAlloc'))
```

```
print(out)

  Description DuAlloc  Amount
0        Blah       1   200.0
0        Blah       2   200.0
0        Blah       3   200.0
0        Blah       4   200.0
0        Blah       5   200.0
1        Yada      30    40.0
1        Yada      15    40.0
1        Yada       3    40.0
1        Yada       4    40.0
1        Yada       5    40.0
```